# Query performance comparision

Tags: sql-server, database, query-optimization, query-performance

On MSSQL Server, I ran two queries which returned same records with different statistics. Can someone guide me on which one is better to use for reporting purpose, with following statistics:

**Query 1:**

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 359 ms, elapsed time = 602 ms.

(5517 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table1'. Scan count 5972, logical reads 37742, physical reads 87, read-ahead reads 32, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table2'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3061, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 3084, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table3'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4171, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 4210, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table4'. Scan count 1, logical reads 843, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 874, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table5'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6899, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 6898, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table6'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3176, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 3207, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table7'. Scan count 2, logical reads 35, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 71, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table8'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 484 ms,  elapsed time = 16415 ms.
```

**Query 2:**

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 312 ms, elapsed time = 618 ms.

(5517 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 11655, logical reads 807704, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table8'. Scan count 0, logical reads 11452, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table1'. Scan count 5976, logical reads 24654, physical reads 15, read-ahead reads 3348, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table2'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3061, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 3084, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table3'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4171, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 4210, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table4'. Scan count 1, logical reads 843, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 874, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table5'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6899, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 6898, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table6'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3176, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 3207, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Table7'. Scan count 2, logical reads 35, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 71, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1342 ms,  elapsed time = 15448 ms.
```

**where:**
Table 7 and 8 are look-up tables, while others are transaction tables.

**From Execution Plan - that differs**
FORMAT: Attribute - Query 1/Query2

```
**SELECT NODE**
Cached Plan Size - 200/168 KB
Memory Grant - 32088/38816
Estimated Subtree Cost - 26.1473/24.4291
Estimated No. of Rows - 104.17/13848.8

**LAST NODE/OPERATOR**
Estimated Operator Cost - 0.0125/0.8858
Estimated Subtree Cost - 26.1473/24.4291
Estimated CPU Cost - 0.0011897/0.874608
Estimated I/O Cost - 0.00112613/0.0112613
Estimated No. of Rows - 104.17/13848.8
Actual No. of Rows - 5517/5517
```

Comment: seems almost identical, but statistics can drastically change for different parameter. we are more interested in actual execution plan.

Comment: send tables schema your querys and statistics to generate similar scenarios, and let us know your sql server version and your parameters.

Comment: The query plans are much more useful. Logical reads are mostly worthless because they are redundant to the CPU usage.

Comment: I've updated the question with the execution plan statistics. Can you look at it again. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @sMajeed, something you might not know is that you can 'ping' a user by including the 'at' symbol in front of their name in your comment, as I've done within this one.  That can be helpful so that users know when you respond to their questions - being pinged shows up as a new message.

Comment: @AHiggins, :) many thanks! I'm new to it and didn't know many things about it. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi @NeerajPrasadSharma, I've added the execution logs, can you take a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @usr, I've added the execution plan, can you take a look at it? Thanks

Comment: I don't see any execution plan. Post images of the two actual execution plans.

Comment: @usr, yes am unable to post the images because on insufficient reputation, so I put the text statistics, which I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after waiting for quite long and analyzing both queries based on different performance statistics,  I couldn't find a way to use one over another. Finally, I ran both the queries with data set of 55K records, and Query 1 returned the results in 13sec, while Query 2 took around 18sec. I used it as benchmark to move forward with Query 1.

Comment: what if you change parameters for the query consider that as well

Comment: In my case, there is only one query parameter, which is input thru the system and hence, we're not expecting that to be changed. So was concerned about the performance, using the same parameter.